# How to stop getting back AutoResponded code for an Envelope

Tags: java, docusignapi

I know the fact that in case of an invalid email address DocuSign sends back AutoResponded as an envelope status. So, whenever I get back AutoResponded some of my services break. Is there a way to turn this feature off of my DocuSign account?

In simple words just ignore if an status is AutoResponded.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to ignore if status is AutoResponsed? Are you using docusign Connect?

Comment: Basically I don't want any bounce back email in this case from DocuSign, if possible. The envelope will still show up on the connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the AutoResponded recipientEventStatusCode from the eventNotification.

Here is a sample CreateEnvelope request which includes all eventNotifications. You can remove the events that you do not want to receive.

```
{

    "eventNotification": {
        "url": "[Callback Url]",
        "loggingEnabled": "true",
        "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
        "envelopeEvents": [
            { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Delivered" },
            { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed" },
            { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined" },
            { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided" },
            { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent" }
        ],
        "recipientEvents": [
            { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent" },
            { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Delivered" },
            { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed" },
            { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Declined" },
            { "recipientEventStatusCode": "AuthenticationFailed" },
            { "recipientEventStatusCode": "AutoResponded" }
        ],
    },

    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "name": "john smith",
                "email": "johnsmith@foo.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Agreement ",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "documentBase64": "[Document Bytes]"
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Envelope for auto responded status"
}
```