# How to manage API rate limit in application before moving to production account?

Tags: docusignapi

We are currently using Sandbox developer account and integrated this with our application. We need to move the production account soon. For that I have referred guidelines related to Golive and based that you have restrictions on API limits.

Following is the excerpt taken from https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview

> ### API Rules and Limits
>
> To maintain reliability and stability within our demo and production
>   environments DocuSign has the following API rules and rate limits in
>   place:
>
> Rule #1: You may not exceed 1,000 API requests per account per hour.
>
> Rule #2: You may not exceed 1 GET request per unique envelope
>   endpoint per 15 minutes.

In our application we make the following calls:

1. Status polling call: @base_uri@/restapi/v2/accounts//envelopes/ - Every 1 minute
   (Note: Our requirement is that user should be notified immediately once document review completes.)
   After this call, once we get response of document status as "Completed" we make following two more calls.
2. Get the signed document IDs(@base_uri@/restapi/v2/accounts//envelopes//documents)
3. Download signed document (@base_uri@/restapi/v2/accounts//envelopes//documents/)

As a whole we make three calls frequently that doesn't comply with Rule#2.

As I have referred from docusign stackoverflow forum, it is mentioned that Rule#2 is specific for GET status API call only not for all such GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/... API patterns. Please clarify this and let us know the exact API you restrict as part of rate limit.

Please let us know if you have any suggestions/inputs so that it doesn't break API limits and our requirement also fulfilled.

## Currently we don't use Webhook solution as no plan expose callback url. So we want to go with polling solution.

Thanks for the reply.

I went through webhook section and based on that we need to send eventNotification object while we create envelopID.

Below is the code. { "eventNotification": { "url": "http://yourappname/callback", "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false", "includeDocuments": "true", "includeDocumentFields": "true", "requireAcknowledgment": "true", "envelopeEvents": [{ "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed", }] } }

Now what parameters/data sends as part of Notification XML on mentioned callback url.

This we need to handle from our application.

Please help to share the details.

Answer (score 1):

Your integration will not pass the Docusign Go Live process with your present implementation.

The DocuSign recommended approach is to use [Webhooks](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#docusign-connect) to receive envelope notifications.

Another options is to use the [CarbonCopy](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#carbon-copies-recipient) recipient and poll the recipients mailbox instead of DocuSign Api.

> Carbon copy recipients get a copy of the envelope but don't need to sign, initial, date or add information to any of the documents. This type of recipient can be used in any routing order. Carbon copy recipients receive their copy of the envelope when the envelope reaches the recipient's order in the process flow and when the envelope is completed.

---

**Rule #2: You may not exceed 1 GET request per unique envelope endpoint per 15 minutes.**
Documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#api-rules)

> For rule #2, the following REST and SOAP calls are included:
>
> - REST API: GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/...
> - SOAP API: RequestStatus, RequestStatusEx, RequestStatuses, RequestStatusesEx,RequestPDF and RequestDocumentPDFs

Comment: I went through webhook section and based on that we need to send eventNotification object while we create envelopID.

Now what parameters/data sends as part of Notification XML on mentioned callback url "http://yourappname/callback".
This we need to handle from our application.
Please help to share the details.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42801483/1219543) for example of notification XML.  Here is the [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definition-eventNotification) for eventNotification